# REACT JS APP IS NOT SHOWING IN LOCALSERVER

Tags: reactjs, express

I have created a React js app but I am getting this code now when I try and run it.

```
  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (/Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
at handleParseError (/Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
at/Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
at /Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
at /Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
/Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
 ^

 Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (/Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
at /Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
at /Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
at /Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at /Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (/Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at /Users/ritamiranda/Desktop/mern/client/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
  }

  Node.js v18.4.0
  ritamiranda@Ritas-MacBook-Air client %
```

I am pretty clueless what could have possibly gone wrong, so any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's you Node version installation issue, please downgrade it to the Latest Stable version (LTS), and delete the node_modules folder in react app and run it after npm install.